# Find the date of a monday based on date of another day in php

Tags: php, date

I need to find a way to get the date of the monday of a week based on another day. So for example, if wednesday is 2011-05-11, i need to somehow tell it that monday of that week was 2011-05-09. Can anyone help?

`$res` looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
        (
            [link_count] => 1
            [day] => 2011-05-12
            [weekday] => Thu
        )

    $days = array(1=> 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
    foreach($res as $r) {
        $day = date('N', strtotime($r->day));
        $r->weekday = $days[$day];
        if($r->weekday == 'Mon') {
            $r->weekstarting = $r->day;
        } else {
            // here's the problem right here, I need to find a way to tell it 
            // what it's starting day is
            $r->weekstarting = ;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You wrote the same date twice. The Monday in the past or in the future?

Comment: Sorry, the monday in the past. This program assumes that the first day of the week is monday. so it always needs to find the monday in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have the weekday (like 'Thu'), so you need to get is position in your `$days` array.

You can get the key with `$key=array_search($r->weekday, $days);` (returns `4`).

Now you know the difference from Monday, so you just have to create the date:

```
$tempArray=explode('-', $r->day);
$tempArray[2]-=$key-1;
$r->weekstarting = implode('-', $tempArray);
```

**EDIT:** Now I see that you already had the array index in `$day`. So you could use that value instead of the `$key` I had.

**EDIT 2:** If you don't want to lose the leading zeros in the day, you could use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-4035) on it .

```
$tempArray=explode('-', $r->day);
$tempArray[2]=sprintf('%02d', $tempArray[2]-($key-1));
$r->weekstarting = implode('-', $tempArray);
```

And finally the **LAST UPDATE**. I was thinking about deleting the whole post and rewriting it again, but I will leave it here for reference... somebody might learn from my mistake.

So the final code that will correctly adjust months also:

```
list($y, $m, $d)=explode('-', $r->day);
$timestamp=mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d-($day-1),$y);
$r->weekstarting = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Actually this is what I wanted to avoid, converting to a timestamp, but I could not. The trick I'm using here is that [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) will handle negative numbers for days and calculate the timestamp correctly.

Comment: unless it's a monday, a 0 is stripped from the date. any idea why?
([weekday] => Mon [weekstarting] => 2011-05-02) ([weekday] => Wed [weekstarting] => 2011-05-2)

Comment: Yes, because it is treated as a number when you change it (`$tempArray[2]-=$key-1;`), so the leading zero is removed. I will add some update to my answer in a second.

Comment: After that last edit, the dates are no longer correct. It returns a date that's after the original. (day: 2011-04-21, weekstarting: 2011-04-22). Any idea?

Comment: One last issue, for dates like 2011-05-01 (Sunday) it returns 2011-05--5. Im guessing because it needs to go back to a previous month. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Drew Yeah, I just copied my first example :).

Comment: @Drew Wow, I did not take that into account :). Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Drew See the **LAST UPDATE** in my post.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine:

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime("11 May 2011");
$dt->modify("last monday");
```

edit: I remember seeing reports that some people had problems with the "last" modifier (windows users maybe) so this should work if you have problems with that:

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime("12 May 2011");
$days = (int)$dt->format('N') - 1;
$dt->modify("-{$days} days");
```

Comment: it just returns nothing at all. it's strange.

Comment: DateTime was added in PHP 5.0 I believe. If you're still using PHP4 you should upgrade, PHP4 is now long since end of lifed

Answer (score 1):

Please create a testfile and execute it:

```
<?php
$dates = array(
    '11 May 2011',
    '2011-04-26',
    '2011-05-04',
);

foreach($dates as $date) {
    $dt = new DateTime($date);
    $dt->modify("last monday");
    printf("For %s last monday is %s.\n", $date, $dt->format('Y-m-d'));
}
?>
```

it should output the following:

```
For 11 May 2011 last monday is 2011-05-09.
For 2011-04-26 last monday is 2011-04-25.
For 2011-05-04 last monday is 2011-05-02.
```

In case not, please add your output to your question above.

Comment: Class DateTime isn't found.. How do i go about using this?

Comment: Okay, that's an info to work with. Just get a recent PHP version, at least PHP 5.2.0 or above. [See here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
$dow = date('N', strtotime($r->day)) - 1; // 0 will be Monday, 1 Tuesday, etc.
$start = mktime() - ($dow * 86400); // 86400 is one day in seconds
$startday = date('r', $start);
```

Comment: this returns: Mon, 09 May 2011 15:43:41 +0000 all I need it to return is 2011-05-09. How do i do that?

Comment: $startday = date('Y-m-d', $start);

Comment: This doesn't work. for 2011-04-26 it returns 2011-05-09. for 2011-05-04, it returns 2011-05-09, for 2011-05-12, it returns 2011-05-09. So something isn't right.